# Unable to get mySQL Dump

Tags: mysql

I m trying to get a mysql dump of my bugtracker tool. MySQl is installed with the WAMP server and i m trying to get the dump from the mySQL console with the following command:

```
mysqldump -uroot -p[password] dbname>/DBBackup/dbname_18052017.sql;
```

but i m getting an error as there is a syntax error,

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'mysqldump -uroot -p[password]
>   dbname>/DBBackup/dbname_18052017.sql;' at line 1 can some one help me
>   figure out this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mysqldump` is a utility program. It's not a SQL statement.

Execute `mysqldump` from the shell prompt just like you execute the `mysql` command line interface program.

---

**FOLLOWUP**

By WAMP, we take that to mean you are running on Windows (not Linux). For Windows...

Start -> Run -> "`cmd.exe`" enter

Change directory to the location of the MySQL binaries

```
> cd C:\Program Files\MySQL Server 5.6\bin
```

This is going to be the directory that contains "`mysqldump.exe`". The actual name of the directory is going to depend on where MySQL was installed as part of WAMP.

Then

```
> mysqldump.exe -u user -pmypassword --quick dbname >C:\somedir\backup_20170518_dbname.sql
```

(Windows will look for an executable in the "current directory". Otherwise, it needs to be in a directory included `%PATH%` environment variable. Or, you can fully qualify the name of the executable.

Comment: Hi @spencer7593 , thank you for the comment. Can I use command prompt for this and when I try to execute it in command prompt i get the error as , mysqldump is not recognised, Since I have not installed mysql separately and given the environment paths, so should I install separately or is there anyother way I can do it?

Comment: On windows, yes, I'd expect it to be cmd.exe.  Likely, the %PATH% environment variable does not include the directory for the MySQL binaries. I don't think you need or want a second install of MySQL Server. (That wouldn't really address the actual problem.)